# Android Studio - KorGE plugin - build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, korge

I would like to use Open Source [KorGE](https://korlibs.soywiz.com/korge/) Game Engine.
I'm using Android Studio and I would like to know if anyone know how to import the library. I've installed the plugin following the [setup documentation](https://korlibs.soywiz.com/korge/setup/).
Could anyone show me how to setup right my build.gradle?
Thanks in Advance

UPDATE:
Following @soywiz suggestion this problem occurred:
[image: compiling error]

**UPDATE**
Thanks to soywiz , now I can use KorGe In my Android Project.
Just set in **build gradle**:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
    maven { url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev") }
}
dependencies {
        ...
  }
}

   allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url = 'https://dl.bintray.com/korlibs/korlibs' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev") }
        }
    }
```

and in build.gradle (app):

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korge:korge-android:1.13.3'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock-android:1.11.12'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.kmem:kmem-android:1.10.5'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.kds:kds-android:1.10.12'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma-android:1.11.16'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio-android:1.11.7'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korim:korim-android:1.12.24'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korau:korau-android:1.11.9'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korgw:korgw-android:1.12.18'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.krypto:krypto-android:1.11.1'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korinject:korinject-android:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.klogger:klogger-android:1.10.1'
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use it in an existing Android project? Or just compile an Android game? KorGE artifacts and be found here: https://bintray.com/korlibs/korlibs/korge you can import the -android artifacts directly as long as you include the right bintray repository.

Comment: I want to use it in an existin Androdi Project. KorGE artifacts are not complete, beacause failed sync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way / most up-to-date way to find out the build.gradle requirements is to actually build a project using KorGE.

If you download this repo:
https://github.com/korlibs/korge-hello-world

Then execute:

```
./gradlew installAndroidDebug
```

This will create a folder called `build/platforms/android` containing a  `build.gradle` file with all the details.

The important parts:

```
repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url = 'https://dl.bintray.com/korlibs/korlibs' }
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korge:korge-android:1.13.3'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock-android:1.11.12'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.kmem:kmem-android:1.10.5'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.kds:kds-android:1.10.12'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korma:korma-android:1.11.16'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio-android:1.11.7'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korim:korim-android:1.12.24'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korau:korau-android:1.11.9'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korgw:korgw-android:1.12.18'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.krypto:krypto-android:1.11.1'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.korinject:korinject-android:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.soywiz.korlibs.klogger:klogger-android:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

All the dependencies might change in the future, so my advice is to trigger the hello world android build, so you get an up-to-date `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I am following your instructions, but the compilation fails with a problem. I will add image upside

Comment: Adding build.gradle implementations directly as suggested instead I get the following error: Failed to resolve: com.soywiz.korlibs.korge:korge-android:1.13.3

Comment: It seems that the version in the hello world is wrong. I have updated it already. Plase, make a `git pull` and try again